# Why isn't it possible to have an anonymous object as argument in a function argument list? C++

Tags: c++

For example:

```
struct test
{};

void thing(test())
{}

int main()
{
   thing(test());
}
```

This code would give me error; however, the next example won't give me error:

```
void thing(int())
{}

int main()
{
   thing(int());
}
```

My main question is, why the first example isn't possible and the second one is? Ultimately, both `test` and `int` are types, so I can't think why declaring an anonymous object of `test` in the `thing` function argument list isn't possible whereas declaring an anonymous object of type `int` in the `thing` function argument list is.

Comment: Which compiler accepts the second code sample?

Comment: @juanchopanza  http://ideone.com/C4yMt4

Comment: `void thing(int())` declares a function that accepts a function pointer of type `int(*)()`. Unfortunately, `int()` is a integral constant expression whose value is `0`, which is a null pointer constant before C++14.

Comment: @cpplearner: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cb5a639d42b920a

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit apparently g++ hasn't implemented C++14 null pointer constant :)

Comment: @cpplearner: Hmm, yeah, okay, I see C++14 restricted the null pointer constant for integers to literals. Didn't know that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* possible; it's just that you're doing it wrong.

Here is a declaration of a function taking an unnamed parameter of type `test`:

```
void thing(test);
```

Here is a declaration of a function taking an unnamed parameter of type pointer-to-function-returning-`test`:

```
void thing(test());
```

You want [the former](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7b34d817b2d4a9a), not the latter.

That [your second code example works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cb5a639d42b920a) is actually a magical oddity, stemming from the fact that `int()` is `0` is a valid *null pointer constant*, which may be used to initialise a function pointer; [the example breaks as soon as you swap `int()` for some other integer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bde13f0477a1126c), or if you run the code in a completely compliant C++14 compiler (because [C++14 made it so that `0` but not `int()` is a valid null pointer constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL)).